# Animating a queue of elements are skipping to final element

Tags: javascript, html, animation

### [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/vPyvOe?editors=1000)

**Rules:**

- Every click will add a `<progress>` element.
- Each progress bar will animate to full.
- Animations wont start until previous has finished.

**Problem:**

If you click rapidly it will only animate the last `progress` bar. And animations should happen one by one until completion.

**Question:**

When clicking rapidly, why are the animations out of order?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="add-progress-container">
    <input class="input-seconds" type="number" min="1" max="10" value="1">
    <button class="add-progress">Add progress</button>
  </div>  
  <div class="progress-container"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
const container = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
const inputSeconds = document.querySelector('.input-seconds');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-progress');
let animating = false;


function animateProgress(duration, el) {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if(el.value >= el.max) {
      animating = false;
      window.clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log('finished');
      checkQueue();
      return;
    }

    el.value += el.max/duration;
  }, 1000);
} 


function getSeconds() {
  return parseInt(inputSeconds.value, 10);
}

let progressCount = 0;

function createProgress() {
  const template = `<progress data-progress="${progressCount}" value="0" max="100"></progress>`;
  container.innerHTML += template;
  const el = document.querySelector(`[data-progress="${progressCount}"]`);
  progressCount++;
  return el;
}

let queue = [];
function addProgress() {
  const el = createProgress()
  queue.push(el);
  checkQueue();
}

function checkQueue() {
  if(queue.length && !animating) {
    animating = true;
    animateProgress(getSeconds(), queue.shift());
  }  
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addProgress);
```

Comment: How're you expecting it should be? Animated one by one whether or not it was clicked rapidly?

Comment: Yeah one by one, even when clicked rapidly

Comment: NB: You have a missing closing square bracket in your selector.

Comment: @trincot good call but not what was breaking it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `innerHTML+=` assignment will recreate all previous elements within the container element, meaning that your references to other `progress` elements are no longer to the actual elements that this assignment creates.

You should add a new progress element like this:

```
function createProgress() {
  const el = document.createElement("progress");
  el.setAttribute("data-progress", progressCount);
  el.setAttribute("value", 0);
  el.setAttribute("max", 100);
  container.appendChild(el);
  return el;
}
```

As Makyuu commented below, the number of steps for the individual progress elements are only taken when their animations start. This means that if you change the input value, it will apply also to previously created elements (when they have not started animating yet).

If it is intended to use the number of steps as they were indicated *at the moment of element creation*, then modify two lines in your code:

```
queue.push([getSeconds(), el]);
```

and:

```
animateProgress(...queue.shift());
```

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Not sure if you're aware or not. But after you're queuing them you would notice that the progressBar increase was based on current value not when it was inputted.

Comment: In case that behaviour was not intended, see addition to my answer.